# Change Woocommerce checkout "Order Comments" to a text input field with a defined maxlength

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

I would like to change the "Order Comments" field in Woocommerce from a textbox to an input box with maximum characters of 18. Plus change the name to "Order Instructions"

I have found a way to edit the field in functions.php using the following code:

```
// remove Order Notes from checkout field in Woocommerce
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'alter_woocommerce_checkout_fields' );
function alter_woocommerce_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);
    return $fields;
}
```

Can this be done with a filter in functions.php?

Comment: Post locked to stop the [rollback war](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55126267/revisions) that has been occurring on this question. I don't know what's going on there. It looks like mujuonly was making a constructive edit to fix the capitalization of a proper name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated: You can use the following for "Order Comments" checkout field, to:

- Change the field type to an input text
- Set a max length
- Change the label to "Order Instructions"

Here is the code

```
// Change Order Notes type to 'text' on Woocommerce checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'alter_woocommerce_checkout_fields' );
function alter_woocommerce_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    // Change field type
    $fields['order']['order_comments']['type'] = 'text';

    // Limit to a max length
    $fields['order']['order_comments']['custom_attributes'] = array('maxlength' => 18);

    // Change the label name
    $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = __('Order Instructions', "woocommerce");

    return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]